# Xubuntu 14.04 can't get steam installed

Tags: drivers, ati, xubuntu, steam

Installing steam with the software center goes fine. When I try to run steam I get the error "You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libc.so.6"
I have run "sudo apt-get update" and installed amd drivers through additional drivers and terminal with this guide.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

`locate libc.so.6` outputs `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

`sudo apt-get install libc6:i386` tells me to run `sudo apt-get -f install`
which returns

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong there.  I've installed steam twice on two different systems and I know from experience that when it is installed properly, it performs its own updates, rather obsessively, every time it's opened.

I would like to propose you do as I do and only use terminal for those rare occasions when you need to do something you cannot do any other way.  This means no more "sudo apt-get update".  Please humor me and open the update manager manually:

1. press windows button
2. type upd then press enter
3. press check
4. if it finds anything needing of updates, click update.

My guess however is that what's broken is steam, or something else in your system from installing too much unauthorized software using terminal.

Comment: Everything is up to date.